# How can I read auth token from external website (where I logged in)?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, token, bearer-token

There's a Nike website where I have personal account. When I interact with website I can get auth token in Network tab. That's in request headers.

Business scenario:
The user visit my website -> logs in to Nike account -> magic -> I get user's bearer token and can grab data to represent it in beautiful graph and etc.

What should be in 'magic' place?

Maybe separate chrome extenstion could help me with user auth and getting token but I don't know where to start.
I tried getAllResponseHeaders() but it doesn't returns headers with token